# Magento 2: Set backorder status programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, simple-product, backorder

In my case I want to set `backorder` status to 1 (turn it on).
I'm playing around in `module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php` in the `execute()` function.

I can modify array `$data` with all new settings before the product will be saved. And for example if I change `name` it will take effect. But if I change `['stock_data']['backorders']` it will not.

So my question is how to set `backorder` status programmatically on product save? (simple product)

Here's short example of the array:

```
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [name] => Somedress-4
            [sku] => skudress-4
            [price] => 575.00
            ....
            [stock_data] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 87
                    [product_id] => 87
                    [stock_id] => 1
                    [qty] => 5
                    [min_qty] => 0
                    [use_config_min_qty] => 1
                    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
                    [backorders] => 1
                    [use_config_backorders] => 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set `backorder` status programmatically you need to override `/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php` and do this:

```
$stockData = ['backorders' => 0,
              'use_config_backorders' => 1];

$product->setStockData($stockData);
```